# Karate Framework

Tags: javascript, debugging, logging, karate

One of the challenges of using the Karate Framework for testing is that it can be hard to locate the source of failure when a test case fails inside a JavaScript function.This is because the Karate Framework does not provide a detailed stack trace or error message for JavaScript failures, unlike for other types of failures.

DO we have any solution to sort out the mentioned issue.

Developing test script in Karate Framework along with javascript.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: newer versions have better JS stack reporting but it may not be perfect. personally I recommend teams use less JS - and only for small "inline" functions for business logic. for complex re-usable code, use Java. teams that get the best out of karate just call APIs in a sequence and validate responses with little fuss. the max re-use is getting authentication + `configure headers` for all API calls.